# Elastalert unable to change the default UTC timezone

Tags: elasticsearch, elastalert

I am using elastalert in docker. in my dockerfile i have set the timezone however, when i test rule it is using utc. how can we modify it

Dockerfile

```
ENV TZ="<my time zone>"
```